# dropdown is getting overlapped by the popup

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a popup in which I have 2 multiselect dropdown, this was working fine on localhost but when I deployed it dropdown got overlapped by popup, any idea why?

[image]

```
  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class=" col-sm-12 ">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                    <mat-label>Select error fileds</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select [formControl]="errorFieldDll" (selectionChange)="filter($event)" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
                                     multiple>
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let errorField of errorFields" [value]="errorField.value">
                                            {{errorField.viewValue}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                    <mat-label>Select return reason</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select [formControl]="returnReason" (selectionChange)="returnReason($event)" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
                                     multiple>
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let returnReason of returnReasons" [value]="returnReason.value">
                                            {{returnReason.viewValue}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
    </div>
```

Comment: If your csss/scss code is compiled (like in React, VueJs ...), check if once exported/minified during deployment the css result is the same, because in localhost most of the time you code is not minified and sometimes the result can be different.

Comment: Modals are supposed to act like that... Always on top... You can change the Z index of your drop-downs (with css or JS) to override this...